# tocar (a) la puerta vs golpear la puerta

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, sinónimos

I heard the following sentence in the Narcos TV series (which takes place in Colombia):

> Espere un momento, que me están tocando la puerta.

1) Isn't the idiomatic expression "tocar *a* la puerta" ?

2) Is there any difference in meaning between "tocar a la puerta" and "golpear la puerta" ? Could I use the latter in the above sentence?

Comment: I would expect this to have regional variation.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like either regional variation or more probably plain careless speech. In fact I think I've heard *me están golpeando **a** la puerta*, so maybe it's all a bit mixed up. This is anecdotical though.

Comment: Could a Colombian confirm if "tocar la puerta" is usual or if it is careless speech? If this is a regionalism, it would be nice if people from different countries could answer the two questions.

Comment: spanishdict.com tiene "tocar la puerta."  https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/tocar%20la%20puerta

Answer (score 1):

"Tocar *a* la puerta" is "to knock *at* the door".

> He aquí, yo estoy a la puerta y llamo; si alguno oye mi voz y abre la puerta, entraré a él... 
>   -Apocalipsis 3.20 RVR1960
>
> I stand *at the door* and knock...
>   -same, KJV

"Tocar la puerta" is "to knock *on* the door" or simply "to touch the door"

"Golpear la puerta" sounds more forceful, like "to strike the door", or in the case of "golpear a la puerta", "to strike at the door".

Answer (score -1):

1. It is **incorrect** to say "a la puerta". In Spanish you only add "a" to the direct object when it is a **person**, not an object. For example, we say "He visto a Maria" but never "He visto Maria". Actually if you say "tocar a la puerta" I would feel like they are actually touching it, not knocking it.
2. Both "Tocar" and "Golpear" mean the same in this context, I don't see any difference. In the northwest part of Spain they even use another verb, "Petar".

Comment: Where are you from?  Other native speakers do not agree with you: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/tocar-a-la-puerta.1016794/

Comment: I'm Spanish. As you can see in that same post people say that commonly don't use it with preposition "a".

Comment: In the WR thread, there is a Peruvian writer Vargas Llosa quote which uses the expression without the preposition and a Mexican user prefers that same form. A Spanish user and an Argentinian user prefer "tocar a la puerta" when it means "tocar el timbre". Therefore, the most common form depends on the region and your statement that it is *incorrect* to use "tocar a la puerta" is clearly wrong.